# submiting with jQuery no working giving a response from controller codeigniter 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, sweetalert2

i have some problem with jQuery understanding, but in this case, i think i am doing every thing right but not getting result, i you coud help would be good... thank here the code and screenshot

note: if i do it in a regular way adding form action url address to, it does it fine but i want to do it with Ajax...

in the view
notice that i send data from form to console to verify data and it does get it... so form field are not empty...

```
<form id="ubicate">
    <input type="hidden"  id="idusuario" name="idusuario" value="12345612">
    <input type="hidden"  id="tipo" name="tipo" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata( 'nivel' );?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="maplinkform" id="maplinkform" value='No ubicacion disponible'>
    <input type="hidden" id="fechacreado" name="fechacreado" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
    <input id="creadopor" name="creadopor" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata( 'username' );?>">
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ubicate').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Evitar que se envíe el formulario de forma 

            var idusuario = $('#idusuario').val();
            var maplinkform = $('#maplinkform').val();
            var tipo = $('#tipo').val();        
            var creadopor = $('#creadopor').val();
            var fechacreado = $('#fechacreado').val();
            console.log( $('#ubicate').serialize() );

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('paginaprincipal/ubicacionvend') ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            idusuario:idusuario,
            maplinkform:maplinkform,
            tipo:tipo,          
            creadopor:creadopor,
            fechacreado:fechacreado
        },
              success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'success') {
                    // Mostrar un mensaje de confirmación utilizando SweetAlert2
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '¡Éxito!',
                        text: response.message,
                        icon: 'success'
                    });
                } else {
                    // Mostrar un mensaje de error utilizando SweetAlert2
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: response.message,
                        icon: 'error'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
});     
</script>
```

in the controller
i put an exit to test if the Ajax call get into the controller, but the exit is never hit.

```
    public
    function ubicacionvend() {
                $this->load->model( 'model_generico', 'generico' );
        exit('it is inside'); 
        $laubicacion = array(

            'idusuario' => $this->input->post( 'idusuario', "TRUE" ),

            'tiponegocio' => $this->input->post( 'tipo', "TRUE" ),

            'ubicacion' => $this->input->post( 'maplinkform', "TRUE" ),

            'fechacreado' => $this->input->post( 'fechacreado' ),

            'creadopor' => $this->input->post( 'creadopor', "TRUE" )

        );

        $respuesta = $this->generico->guardarUbicacion( $laubicacion );
        if($respuesta){
                // Devuelve un mensaje de éxito
                $response = array(
                  'status' => 'success',
                  'message' => 'Los datos se han insertado correctamente'
                );
              }
              else
              {
                // Devuelve un mensaje de error
                $response = array(
                  'status' => 'error',
                  'message' => 'Ha ocurrido un error al insertar los datos'
                );
              }
              
              echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

in the model

```
     public function guardarUbicacion($field){
        $this->db->insert('ubicaciones', $field);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

screenshot result, where you can notice the messange dos not appear meaning i am not reciving any response.

[image: error with out custom message]

i did it in a normal way adding action to form and it does it right, but i want to do it with Ajax

Comment: check if the url: '<?php echo base_url('pagina principal/ubicacionvend') ?>', gives the correct address

Comment: check the request address in the browser console.

Comment: in the ubicacionvend() method instead of exit('it is inside'); insert http_response_code(200);
echo "Ajax OK";
exit();
And write what showed up

Comment: <?php echo base_url('paginaprincipal/ubicacionvend') ?> is not the problem, it is the same i used from form action when i do the test as a regular submit

Comment: here it is  http_response_code(200); echo http_response_code();  echo "Ajax OK"; exit(); and come nothing, it is not enterint to controller method.. why? i don't know... for me it seem to be ok.. but does not work

Comment: try relative url in your ajax function... `url: '/paginaprincipal/ubicacionvend',` and eventually check your routes.php

Comment: i did a test    window.location = "<?php echo base_url("/paginaprincipal/ubicacionvend/")?>";
and the location, precedure or writting are ok, the problem definitly is not the location

Comment: you can also observe in your browser's network tab what is going on with the ajax call, can you take any conclusions from there?

Comment: in the logs directory you have log files - check if anything new appears there when you fire ajax

Answer (score 1):

already solve the problem, a did change data collecting and add dataType:json and that finaly solve the problem, now working good.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ubicate').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Evitar que se envíe el formulario de forma 

      console.log( $('#ubicate').serialize() );

        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('paginaprincipal/ubicacionvend') ?>',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#ubicate').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
              success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'success') {
                    // Mostrar un mensaje de confirmación utilizando SweetAlert2
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '¡Éxito!',
                        text: response.message,
                        icon: 'success'
                    });
                } else {
                    // Mostrar un mensaje de error utilizando SweetAlert2
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: response.message,
                        icon: 'error'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

[image: picture with final result screen]